# If an element $g \in G$ has $|g| = |G|$, then is $g$ automatically the cyclic generator of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is the following statement true for all groups in general?  If the order of an element $g \in G$ is equal to $|G|$ then $G = <g>$?

And thus, if a group does not have an element that is of the same order as the group itself then it cannot be cyclic.

Comment: Yes, the order of an element is the cardinality of the subgroup it generates. This fact is true either by definition, or by inspection of the definition of *order*.

Comment: Yes, this is obvious (for finite groups). The order of an elements equals the order of the subgroup generated by that element. In particular, if $|g|=|G|$, then $<g>$ has $|G|$ elements, and so it is the whole $G$.

Comment: Yes, that would make sense.  Thank you.

Comment: The statement is true in general.  And, yes, a finite group is cyclic (by definition) if and only if it has an element that generates it, i.e. has order equal to the size of the group.

Comment: Shall I delete this question?

Comment: @PiccolMan: No, it seems like a perfectly reasonable and well-posed question. Of course, I am biased: If you delete the question then I believe I lose the rep I gained from the upvotes to my answer. But also you'll lose any rep you gain from upvotes to the question. You might as well leave it; it might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 3):

For each $g \in G$ we have $\langle g \rangle \le G$. But if $G$ is finite group and $|g|=|G|$ then we have that $\langle g \rangle$ is contained in a group of the same order as itself, so it must be the actual group itself. Hence $\langle g \rangle = G$.

On the other hand for $G$ to be cyclic it must have a generator, i.e. an element $g \in G$ s.t. for each $a \in G$ there exists a natural number $n$ s.t. $g^n = a$. This implies that order of $g$ is greater or equal than $|G|$. But as $|g|$ divide $|G|$ we must have $|g| = |G|$.

Therefore a finite group $G$ is cyclic iff there is an element $g \in G$ s.t. $|g| = |G|$

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If $A\subseteq B$ and $A$ and $B$ are finite sets of equal cardinality, then clearly $A=B.$ The result now follows since the subgroup generated by $g,$ which is by definition cyclic, has the same number of elements as $G.$

Answer (score 0):

Yes for **finite** groups (this may not apply for infinite cardinalities), if the order of $g$ is $|G|$, then it would be a contradiction to assume otherwise that $g$ is not the cyclical generator of $G$. $g^n$ produces $n$ different elements (including the identity). By definition, $<g>$ is a subgroup with the same cardinality as $G$, so it must be that $$<g> = G$$